# Burst Photos / Blink app

Tags: blink

I have a Lumia 520 powered with 5MP rear camera. Photos captured has a resolution of 2592*1456 in 16:9 ratio.

I tried Photo burst with [Blink](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/blink/9wzdncrfhx5d) app , which can capture 16 images in 3-4 seconds. Its pretty great actually for taking continuous shots but the output quality of images is pathetic, just 0.3MP resolution i.e; 708*396.

Is it because of my Low quality camera or does every lumia (even 1020) get the same resolution though this app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in quality or resolution between the burst mode and regular photo **depends on the hardware** itself and not the app. However it all depends on the procesing time and the buffer size a device can handle. It **does not depend on the resolution** of the camera.

See this answer [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/50236) which says,

> Some cameras may lower the resolution or quality of the images taken
> in burst mode to lower processing time needed to keep up with the
> higher rate of exposures.

---

### Detailed Explanation

**What is burst mode?**

Burst or continuous high speed is a shooting mode in still cameras. In burst mode several photographs are captured in quick succession.

**Can I take photos on full resolution in Burst mode?**

Yes, you can. Burst mode by itself should not rduce the resolution at all.

**Then why do I get low quality images on burst mode?**

An article [here](http://www.photoreview.com.au/tips/shooting/Burst-Modes-and-How-They-Work) says,

> digital cameras rely on the speed of the data processing system and
> the size of the internal 'buffer' memory where the image is stored
> while it awaits processing.

If your device/camera hardware is not capable of processing a large number of high resolution photos or if the buffer size it can hold is reduced then the photos resolution will be reduced.

---

**References :**

1. [Burst Modes and How they work - Photoreview.com](http://www.photoreview.com.au/tips/shooting/Burst-Modes-and-How-They-Work)
2. [Burst mode - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_mode_(photography))
3. [What are the downsides of leaving my camera in burst mode all the time? - photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/what-are-the-downsides-of-leaving-my-camera-in-burst-mode-all-the-time)
4. [Lower quality photos in burst mode - photo.stackexchange.com](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50230/lower-quality-photos-in-burst-mode)

Comment: What phone do you have and what's the resolution of images you get with blink? is it same 0.3MP?

Comment: @RamRaj I have a Lumia 430 which has a **2MP camera**. I could not get blink to work on my phone. It always says "Capure failed please restart". However I have taken some photos when running 8.1 and they are of the size **800x450**.

Comment: Okay, thanx for the info dude!